# Excel formula to count unique cells in column Q with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I put together this sumproduct formula which works to calculate total sales using a few criteria

- Column G Sheet 2 : brand Name
- Cell A2 Sheet 1 = Brand name
- Column AE Sheet 2 = Transaction date column - which is converted to Year (B13) and Month (C1)
- Column AY Sheet 2 = Transaction value total

`=SUMPRODUCT(--('Sheet2'!$G2:$G10000='Sheet1'!$A$2),--(YEAR('Sheet2'!$AE2:$AE10000)='Sheet1'!$B13),--(MONTH('Sheet2'!$AE2:$AE10000)='Sheet1'!C$1),'Sheet2'!$AY2:$AY10000)`

The end result which works: Calculates total sales based on 3 criteria, month, year and brand.

How can I modify this formula to instead calculate the total unique cells (customers) in column Q on sheet 2?

I assumed it would be as easy as modifying my sum array which is bold in the formula above but I have not figured it out.

If it helps, i do have two formulas which gives me the total unique cell count in the column, I just can't figure out how to add either into my formula..

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE('Sheet2'!Q2:Q10000))

=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF('Sheet2'!Q2:Q27932,'Sheet2'!Q2:Q10000))
```

Comment: Use `UNIQUE(FILTER())`  where the FiLTER does the conditionals and the UNIQUE returns the unique list, then count it

Answer (score 0):

The solution that another user provided on another form was

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet2!$Q2:$Q10000,
(Sheet2!$G2:$G10000=$A$2)*
(YEAR(Sheet2!$AE2:$AE10000)=$B13)
*(MONTH(Sheet2!$AE2:$AE10000)=C$1))))
```